# context id is not available for @FeignClients Annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am new to micro services and using spring boot.

I have Spring cloud version as `<spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>`

and spring version as `<version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>`

My project uses spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.0.0M.1.jar

In that Annotation is

```
@FeignClient(name = "ABC")
```

I want to insert contextId like below

```
@FeignClient(contextId = "dummy", name = "ABC")
```

But in I am not getting able to get ContextId in suggestions it shows me compile time Error

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: Hi @YCF_L I am not getting any error but I am not able to import that in my FeignClient annotation as parameter.

Comment: are you importing `import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;`?*

Comment: yes import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient; both are imported it works with the name parameter fine but cannot find parameter for context id

Comment: Finchley.M8 is an unsupported milestone. Please try again with Greenwich.SR4